# Automating capturing screenshort including chrome devtools window

Tags: google-chrome, automation, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

For analysing our website speed, we usually take screenshots of our page along with chrome-devtool reports like memory, performance etc. I want to automate that process. 
I tried some tools like a puppeteer. But it only taking screenshots of the website. Not including devtools UI in it.

Is there any tool or method to load webpage with chrome-devtools, do some testing and take a screenshot of that page including chrome-devtools window?

Sample screenshot which I expect

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is very broad.  Please clarify: 

- do you intend to do this in a CI environment or manually via some local script?
- what information do you want from devtools?  You show the 'performance' tab; is that it?

Between `puppeteer` and chrome devtools protocol, you can do almost anything.

Comment: @Peter Want to take some performance matrix like memory, heap size, etc and take screenshot of the webpage with devtool window in it for making reports. Now we are manually doing this process. I want to automate it.I am new to puppeteer but i managed to run all these tests using it. But cant take screenshot of the page with devtool screen. In puppeteer, I only getting webpage screen. Not including the devtools screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of nice open source project in NodeJs that lets you take screenshots. Are you using Node ?

Check out this one: [screenshot-desktop](https://github.com/bencevans/screenshot-desktop#readme)